# I cannot see turtoisesvn on windows server after installing it

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows-server-2008

I just installed tortoisesvn on windows server 2008 but it is not showing any menus for tortoise when i right click any folder. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a 64-bit Windows and installed the 32-Bit version of Tortoise.

Install the 64-Bit version as well. Both versions can be installed parallelly. It even makes sense to do so: 64-Bit Explorer needs 64-Bit Tortoise, but other 32-Bit apps may need 32-Bit Tortoise.